# Is the HP LaserJet PRO M130fw compatible with Linux?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I'm about to buy a Laserjet multifunction wireless printer, and I was thinking about the [HP LaserJet Pro M130fw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LBWELFK)

I searched online for a while and all I could find is [this thread on the Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=242899)

And [this on hp forums](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Ubuntu-15-04-compatibility-with-HP-Laser-Jet-MFP-M130fw/td-p/5972643).

Anybody had luck using this printer on Linux? Or should I go for a similar model with better Linux support?

Comment: I would suggest buying it at a retail store that will price match Amazon, such as Staples or Microcenter. That way you can easily return it if it doesn't  work properly :)

Comment: It does appear on the hplip's list of supported printers: you need the latest version of hplip; so one would best purge hplip in ubuntu and download and install hplip direct; .. it should set up fine; http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_mfp_m129-m134.html I enclose the link that talks of it and no driver plugins are needed; good advice above

Comment: Did you end up buying it? If so, did it work ok?

Comment: In the end I bought a LaserJet M1132 MFP, it works, kind of, sometimes I loose connection, and I couldn't get it working on an arch based linux, on ubuntu it seems to work

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think this question would be better suited to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Shopping recommendations are [off topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off-topic according to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

YES. It's working with the new LTS version of Ubuntu, 18.04, and out of the box! It appears that it gives you the option to use different printers (in reference to the drives and such), so select the appropriate one, in this case being the hp laserjet pro m130fw. Although it is using the hp laserjet m129 as its driver, you still have to point to the printer, being the m130. It'll work. Does that make sense?

Comment: Mark this as solved, unless you're using an earlier brand of Ubuntu. The only real fix is to upgrade to at least the Ubuntu 18.04, and be done with it. I know, easier said than done.

Answer (score 2):

I am professional at installing printers on Ubuntu, but I tried my best and I could not install it on my laptop.

- Printer : HP LaserJet Pro MFP M130fw
- Ubuntu : Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

I tried, USB / wireless, with and without hplip.

So, maybe it is late but for the future users, I am not suggesting it for Ubuntu so far.

Comment: This is an answer: it's stating that it's not practicable to use this printer with an Ubuntu system. "It's impossible" is a valid answer.

Comment: My question is "is it compatible with linux?", and @karianpour's answer is "no", it is of course a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS: 
Visited https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing and downloaded the latest **hplip** program from their site. After you do the same, open terminal (ctrl+alt+t), change to the directory where it was downloaded (`cd directory_name`) and run the program with commands:

```
sudo chmod +x hplip-[DOWNLOADED_VERSION].run
./hplip-[DOWNLOADED_VERSION].run
```

(obviously change the [DOWNLOADED_VERSION] to the one you've downloaded).
The setup takes some time but is pretty straight forward, just remember to overwrite the existing version of the program as ubuntu 14 already has it (but not in the latest version it seems).

After that I could easily add the printer via the installed HP Device Manager. It prints fine. Didn't test the scanning option yet but I got it working on another machine (with ubuntu 18.04 however) and I suppose it can be done as well.